# How to unhide an element from javascript execute() method?

Tags: javascript, html, css, webdriver-io

I'm doing automation using WDIO and want to upload a file but the input element is disabled. The style element of the input selector has :

[image]

When I change it to this, element is visible

[image]

I wish to change this through my javascript code, this is what I've tried so far:

```
const inputFilePath = "#kyc-image-file-input";
await this.driver.execute(
   (elem) => elem.style.display = 'block',
   await this.driver.$(inputFilePath),
 );
 await WaitUtil.pause(this.driver, 5000);
 await (await this.digioPage.getPanAndAadhaarUploadFileInputEle()).setValue(remoteFilePath);
 await WaitUtil.pause(this.driver, 5000);
```

Javascript throws the below error when I do this:
[image]

Please let me know the correct way of changing the display property.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What's the error thrown when you include the hyphen?

Comment: Cannot find name 'none'.

Comment: Might need to show a bit more of your code to figure out exactly what's happening I think, can you update the OP?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change style:

```
(elem) => elem.style.display = 'block'
```

Comment: The style element is empty

Comment: I have tried this as well, didn't work

Comment: It says the element was not found

Answer (score 0):

Try this, selecting the element you want to change:

```
const inputFilePath = "#kyc-image-file-input";

await this.driver.execute(
   (elem) => document.querySelector(elem).style.display = 'block',
   await this.driver.$(inputFilePath)
 );
```

Comment: invalid element state: invalid element state: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[object HTMLInputElement]' is not a valid selector.

Comment: @AmanSinha Would you be able to update your OP with your HTML snippet? Is the element that you're trying to change the style of definitely present in the DOM?